# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getParentFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, 
                                   R.id.navigation_notifications))
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}


 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
> getParentFragmentManager()Landroidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager; in
> class Landroidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment; or its super
> classes (declaration of 'androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment'
> appears in
> /data/app/~~MGLc4E8e1G_cs0ZWkl7w2Q==/com.trend.topcar-cfc6kzaHX2ROCl0ZEzapbw==/base.apk)
> at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onAttach(NavHostFragment.java:197)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:2574)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:828)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1393)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3205)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
> at com.trend.topcar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:16)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7973)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)

Comment: Could you include what library versions you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for support fragment manager . getParentFragmentManager()
and it should work.